# Include not working when loading related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am quite new to Entity Framework Core and I am having some trouble loading related entities when using multiple `.Include()`.

The entities are the following:

```
public class AppointmentModel
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public DateTime AppointmentDateAndTime { get; set; } 
     public int CustomerId { get; set; }
     public CustomerModel Customer { get; set; }
     public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
     public EmployeeModel Employee { get; set; }
     public int StatusId { get; set; }
     public AppointmentStatusModel Status { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<ServiceSelectedModel> ServicesSelected { get; set; }

 }

 public class AppointmentStatusModel
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public AppointmentModel Appointment { get; set; }

 }

    public class CustomerModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public AppointmentModel Appointment { get; set; }
    }

  public class EmployeeModel
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }
      public string Email { get; set; }
      public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
      public AppointmentModel Appointment { get; set; }

  }

  public class ServiceSelectedModel
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public int ServiceId { get; set; }
      public ServiceModel Service { get; set; }
      public int AppointmentId { get; set; } 
      public AppointmentModel Appointment { get; set; }
  }
```

The `AppointmentModel` has a one to one relationship with `EmployeeModel`, `CustomerModel` and `AppointmentStatusModel, and a one to many relationship with` ServiceSelectedModel`.

The relationship configuration is as follows:

```
var appointment = modelBuilder.Entity<AppointmentModel>();


appointment.HasOne<CustomerModel>(x => x.Customer)
           .WithOne(x => x.Appointment)
           .HasForeignKey<AppointmentModel>(x => x.CustomerId);
appointment.HasOne<EmployeeModel>(x => x.Employee)
           .WithOne(x => x.Appointment)
           .HasForeignKey<AppointmentModel>(x => x.EmployeeId);
appointment.HasOne<AppointmentStatusModel>(x => x.Status)
           .WithOne(x => x.Appointment)
           .HasForeignKey<AppointmentModel>(x => x.StatusId);
appointment.HasMany<ServiceSelectedModel>(x => x.ServicesSelected)
           .WithOne(x => x.Appointment)
           .HasForeignKey(x => x.AppointmentId);
```

What I am trying to do is query a list of appointments, with pagination and filtering. The code I am using is the following:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<AppointmentModel>> GetAll(AppointmentPaginationFilteringParameters parameters)
{
    var query = _db.Appointments.AsQueryable();

    if (parameters.CustomerId != null)
    {
        query = query
            .Where(x => x.CustomerId == parameters.CustomerId);
    }

    if (parameters.EmployeeId != null)
    {
        query = query
            .Where(x => x.EmployeeId == parameters.EmployeeId);
    }

    if (parameters.StatusId != null)
    {
        query = query
            .Where(x => x.StatusId == parameters.StatusId);
    }

    return await query
                 .Include(x => x.Employee)
                 .Include(x => x.Customer)
                 .Include(x => x.Status)
                 .Skip((parameters.PageNumber - 1) * parameters.PageSize)
                 .Take(parameters.PageSize)
                 .ToListAsync();
}
```

And the class `AppointmentPaginationFilteringParameters`:

```
public class AppointmentPaginationFilteringParameters
{
    const int maxPageSize = 10;
    public int PageNumber { get; set; } = 1;
    private int _pageSize = 5;

    public int PageSize
    {
        get
        {
            return _pageSize;
        }
        set
        {
            _pageSize = (value > maxPageSize) ? maxPageSize : value;
        }
    }

    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int? EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int? StatusId { get; set; }
}
```

The pagination and filtering is working fine, but some of the related entities are not being loaded. What could be the problem?

Comment: *Which* related entities don't load? And is this the exact class model, you didn't happen to leave out navigation property initializations, did you?

Comment: You will need to be more specific with an example of what you expect to come back and what is actually coming back. The mappings you show don't show a problem, but it would potentially have an issue if you tried running with `AsSplitQuery()` which your example is not. You should always aim to have an `OrderBy` condition when using `Skip` & `Take` to ensure queries are repeatable. Another issue to check is the DbContext's connection string at runtime to ensure it is pointing at the database you are checking against. (This is a more common issue that you might expect)